# How to decode h264 I Frame to RAW Image?

Tags: image, video, h.264

I develop my own RTSP client/server through socket bytestream data.
Now there is a task to extract a raw image (RGB, YUV or smth else) from the video I frame.

Please, show me the way how to do it only through bytestream analysis.
I try to find I frame byte structure but there is no useful info about decoding.

I'll be appreciated if you tell me the right way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by “only through bitstream analysis”. Do you mean you wish to write your own decoder?

Comment: Not clear...  **(1)** _"How to do it only through bytestream analysis"_ depends what you've got, is it raw `.h264` file data or is the h264 data itself contained inside some other format like MP4, FLV or even AVI? **(2)** _"No useful info about decoding"_ What programming language are you using? Does it have video playback ability (an MPEG video decoder)?

Comment: @szatmary, sorry for long reply. Yes, I'm going to write my own decoder

Comment: @VC.One sorry for long reply - (1) - I get it from decoded RTP packets or from recorded raw .264 files. I know about NALUs and I can detect and extract "I" frames from the stream. (2) I use erlang. The main question is about extraction raw image from the frame :)

Comment: @NickSaw I hope you realize the document that describes the h264 decoder specification is over 750 pages long.

Comment: @szatmary which document do you mean? "ITU-T H.264 Recommendations"?I'm sure that most of these 750 pages describe "B" and "P" frame encoding and analysis. As you know, "I" frame contains the whole binary image unlike P and B frames. Therefore I'm sure that it's not a difficult purpose. I'm looking for clear information about it..